# Can't remove mapping from VIM?

Tags: vim

My `vim` configuration is adding some really annoying mappings for the `sql` filetype that conflict with my own.

I can verify it with the following command:

```
:imap <C-c>a

i  <C-C>a      *@<C-\><C-O>:call sqlcomplete#Map("syntax")<CR><C-X><C-O>
```

I want to remove it, but if any way I try it fails:

```
:unmap <C-C>a
E31: No such mapping

:iunmap <C-C>a
E31: No such mapping
```

I can clearly see that the mapping exist so why is it telling me that it doesn't?

Comment: Where are you using the `iunmap` commands? vimrc (which would be before the mapping is put into place)? A buffer with an SQL file?

Comment: It was a buffer with a SQL file. Ingo Karkat's found the issue below. I'll add the colons to the `unmap` commands to make it a bit clear for the next readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*` in the `:imap` output gives it away: This is a *buffer-local* mapping, so in order to unmap it, you also need to specify the `<buffer>` attribute:

```
iunmap <buffer> <C-C>a
```

To undo the ftplugin mapping for all `sql` buffers, put this into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sql.vim`.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting the `<Ctrl-c>` literally by first pressing `Ctrl-v` then `Ctrl-c`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in your first command for listing the mapping, you are using `:imap <C-c>a`, where the second `c` is lowercase, but in the `unmap <C-C>a` commands, your second `C` is uppercase.

Since these commands are generally case-sensitive, I suspect that might be part of your issue.

Comment: Only the Alt mappings are case-sensitive, for Ctrl this (currently) doesn't matter.